# Flex AND iOS push notifications

Tags: ios, apache-flex, air

It's posible build a Flex 4.5.1 and Adobe AIR app for iOS, And use push notifications?

Comment: Did you try something and have issues?  I know that iOS prevents some things; but push is a server side thing.  As long as you have a server that will perform the push, I'd expect you will be good to go.

Answer (score 4):

You have to register for the push notifications inside the app. I'm not sure that Flex provides a method to do this registering.

Answer (score 1):

You have to update your AIR SDK to 3.4 to use push notifications in Flex.There are instructions at [the Adobe site](http://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/multi/how-overlay-air-sdk-flex-sdk.html). HTML to update the air sdk in Flex SDK

Comment: [AIR 3.5 SDK](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/air-sdk-download.html) has been released.  Also, your link is broken - it is: [Overlay AIR SDK on Flex SDK | Flash Builder](http://helpx.adobe.com/x-productkb/multi/how-overlay-air-sdk-flex-sdk.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, but it requires using Native Extensions.  I just wrote a flex app for IOS that uses push and it works quite well.

Comment: Did you write your own ANE, or use one that is publicly available?